# WebSphere MQ write to local queue (Client) or Remote queue

Tags: .net, wcf, ibm-mq

Even with the new patch 7.0.1.7 we are getting an error when we try to write messages to a remote queue using a mult-threaded .Net WCF application. We were on 7.0.1.3 and i found that there were issues with multi-threaded applications so we downloaded the latest patch. Is it simply our architecture? Should we be writing to the local client queue and have it forward the message to the remote queue?

Seems like that could be the issue.

Comment: What's the error?  As a general rule, if you have a local QMgr, use it and let it get the messages ot the remote QMgrs.  Apps should not need to know where each and every queue instance is hosted, they just need access to a QMgr and *it* needs to route the messages to their destination.  I'll wait for Shashi to weigh in on the .Net aspects.

Comment: Hi @T.Rob I looked out on the server itself and I noticed I am getting TCP/IP errors.  I think that is actually what is causing the problem.  Whether I send one to the queue or many I am always getting this error.  Just makes me wonder if this is what is causing the the issue when I spin up multiple instances and not thread contention.  I am using the WCF Channel from IBM which doesn't appear to ahve anything in regards to closing the connection?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is the Error Message: An error occurred receiving data from "machine" and "IP" over TCP/IP. This may be due to a communications failure.  

The return code from the TCP/IP recv() call was 10054 (X'2746'). Record these values and tell the systems administrator.

Comment: Hi @T.Rob sorry for all of the comments....I ran same scenario against my local queue (where the app is) and I am not getting the TCP errors as shown above so it could very well be when we are trying to write / read from a remote queue....although the read from remote queue seems reasonable.

Comment: As you saw the application works with local queue, the issue is with the communication between your application and the queue manager your application connects to. Just to narrow down, try putting a message to  the remote queue using 'amqsputc' sample application and see if that works.